# Angular2 : nested *ngFor + md-select

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, md-select

I'm working on a little project in Angular2 (I'm a beginner).

Basically it involves an array and up to three Material Angular Select forms to pick values from it.

Here is the plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/700zL1tDxml0zQwF6yj6?p=preview

**JS code**

```
this.udlsCarac={ "Ticker1": { "NAME": "Name 1" }, "Ticker2": { "NAME": "Name 2" }, "Ticker3": { "NAME": "Name 3" } };
this.udlsTickers = Object.keys(this.udlsCarac);
this.udls=[];
this.udls.push(this.udlsTickers[0]);
this.nbUdls=1;
this.nbUdlsMax=3;

addUdlSelector(){
  this.udls.push(this.udlsTickers[0]);
  this.nbUdls+=1;
}
removeUdlSelector(){
  this.udls.pop();
  this.nbUdls-=1;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<div *ngFor="let u of udls; let i=index">
  <md-select [(ngModel)]="udls[i]" name="choice">
    <md-option *ngFor="let udl of udlsTickers" [value]="udl">
      {{udlsCarac[udl].NAME}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

**How to replicate the issue**

1 - Select Name 2 or Name 3 on 1st Select

2 - Click "+" button to add a new Select

3 - you can see that the Array of selected values (`this.udls`) is correct but the value of 1st Select has switched to `Name 1`

Could you please give me some help? thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `name` in forms every name has to be unique, otherwise the same value will be applied to all. In your iteration, all end up with the same name, ie. `name="choice"` So make choice unique by adding your index.

```
name="choice{{i}}"
```

and it will work as you want :)

### Your updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5FDAZhXhS7R6euwhSkr0?p=preview)